# No Python at "\python\python.exe" error. Ursina project

Tags: python, ursina

I compiled my ursina project to bat using documentation https://www.ursinaengine.org/building.html. After command

> python -m ursina.build

Folder "build" was created [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejhP1.png)
When i clicked on the bat-file i got an error in log.txt:

> No pyvenv.cfg file

I created pyvenv.cfg file and wrote "home = \python", because without it i got an error

> Cannot find home in

After that my program started to run.

But after i sent that folder (archive) to my friend and he run bat-file he got:

> No Python at "\python\python.exe"

My friend tried to install Python and in pyvenv.cfg he wrote path to it. But it didnt help

What should i do?